# Receive rtsp stream into Docker container

Tags: python, windows, docker, ffmpeg, stream

I've been in a war to get this issue resolved. I have the impression that I have already searched the entire internet...
My goal is to send an rtsp stream from my host (Windows) to a Docker container, to later run machine learning models on the video.

[image: Here is the architecture that seems to me to be the problem.]

**Host (Windows):**

Thanks to [rtsp-simple-server](https://github.com/aler9/rtsp-simple-server) I'm able to get my webcam to generate an rtsp stream.
The rtsp-simple-server.yml looks like (where xxx.xxx.xxx.x is the Windows Host IP):

```
paths:
  cam:
    runOnInit: ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="HP HD Camera" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -b:v 600k -f rtsp rtsp://xxx.xxx.xxx.x:8554/cam
    runOnInitRestart: yes
```

Then I can view the video running a script in python that opens a window for me:

```
import cv2
import os
os.environ["OPENCV_FFMPEG_CAPTURE_OPTIONS"] = "rtsp_transport;tcp"
vcap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://localhost:8554/cam", cv2.CAP_FFMPEG)
while(1):
    ret, frame = vcap.read()
    if ret == False:
        print("Frame is empty")
        break;
    else:
        cv2.imshow('VIDEO', frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
```

**Docker container:**

Now comes the tricky part: How can I get the stream to the Docker container?
I am currently using the Docker image: [jjanzic/docker-python3-opencv](https://hub.docker.com/r/jjanzic/docker-python3-opencv) but when I run the python script I get *"Frame is empty"*... Even changing the *rtsp://localhost:8554/cam* by the Windows Host IP - *rtsp://xxx.xx.xxx.x:8554/cam*

Help please

Comment: First try If you can reach 8554 from docker for example nmap -p 8554 host IP when yes try with rtsp tcp

Comment: Thank you for the help! I ran the command `nmap -p 8554 xxx.xxx.xxx.x` and it seems to have worked  What do you mean with _try with rtsp tcp_?

Comment: How do you Setup simple rtsp Server ? Is it configured to tcp or udp ? I think its under protocols on the yaml config. With tcp I mean set the ffmpeg environ to rtsp_transport;tcp

Comment: Great :) have fun